# Objective-C Bool Question

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am trying to see if a string has more than 6 characters in it.  If it does it is not valid, and like wise for the other.

My problem is I am trying to call this method in a different method.  I am not passing anything but instead I am using a NSString globally.

```
NSString *string = @"123456";
-(BOOL) isValid{

if ([string length] > 6) {
    return YES;
}
else {
    return NO;
}}
```

How do I call this function from another function without passing anything in the parameter?

Comment: Can be much shorter: `return [string length] > 6;`. Oh, it's not a function by the way: it's a method. An instance method to be precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the methods are in the same class:

```
[self isValid];
```

otherwise:

```
[someObject isValid];
```

Comment: Thanks, they were in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL valid = [self isValid];
```

This is the most basic of calls in ObjC. You probably should be starting with a tutorial or book.

Comment: The book I read had it split over two classes.  I did not know to add the self.